# springboot json utf format when use cors

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    }


}
```

it is in my main code when i request data from my database i can not see every character like euro sign but when i delete this then i can see (ineed this because of response) i couldnt figure out what is the problem